# MATLAB moving a point in the XY plane

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I have an XY plane that is represented by finite number of points. The possible values of x are stored in a vector X and the possible values of y are stored in another vector Y. I have a point, say A, such that A(1) belongs to X is the x-coordinate and A(2) belongs to Y is the y-coordinate.

This point A can move in one of 8 ways if it is in the middle:

```
          .   .   .                      .   A                .    .

          .   A   .        OR            .   .       OR       .    A

          .   .   .                                           .     .
```

Of course, the set of these points changes if the point A is on the edge (sometimes only 5, sometimes only 3 if it is a corner). How can I find the set of these "1-hop" neighboring points? What about the set of "k-hop" neighboring points? By set I mean two vectors one for x-coordinates and another for y-coordinates. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, actually I am trying to simulate something in networks and I need this to continue.

Comment: ok no problem, you description sounded homework-y to me

Comment: You haven't defined things well enough to answer.  If X = [1 100] and Y = [7 7] then there are only two places the point can be, and they aren't next to each other, so the point can't move at all.  If all values of X between some min and max are allowed, you need to tell us.  If they are not you need to tell us what you mean by "1-hop" neigbhoring points, what the rules are to hop from one point to another.  Amazingly, if you are able to tell us these things clearly, you will probably find you can code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
%# create grid of 2D coordinates
sz = [5 6];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:sz(2),1:sz(1));

%# point A
A = [1 2]

%# neighboring points
k = 2;                               %# hop size
[sx,sy] = meshgrid(-k:k,-k:k);       %# steps to get to neighbors
xx = bsxfun(@plus, A(1), sx(:));     %# add shift in x-coords
xx = min(max(xx,1),sz(2));           %# clamp x-coordinates within range
yy = bsxfun(@plus, A(2), sy(:));
yy = min(max(yy,1),sz(1));
B = unique([xx yy],'rows');          %# remove duplicates
B(ismember(B,A,'rows'),:) = [];      %# remove point itself
```

The result for the point `A = (1,2)` with `k=2` hops:

```
B =
     1     1
     1     3
     1     4
     2     1
     2     2
     2     3
     2     4
     3     1
     3     2
     3     3
     3     4
```

and an illustration of the solution:

```
x A x x . .
x x x x . .
x x x x . .
. . . . . .
. . . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say `A = [Xcenter Ycenter]`

for K-hop, you can access points:

```
pointsX = [];
pointsY = [];
for i=-k:k
  pointsX = [pointsX  Xcenter+i]; 
  pointsY = [pointsY  Ycenter+i];
end
```

Furthermore, you can filter these points by order coordinates and remove the outliers. e.g. consider

```
(1,1)  (1,2)  (1,3)
(2,1)  (2,2)  (2,3)
(3,1)  (3,2)  (3,3)
```

Now you know that minimum allowed X and Y are 1, so just filter out points with any ordinate and/or abscissa lesser than that.

Comment: Tip: use the `{}` tag to format code nicely (or add 4 spaces before each line to do it by hand).

Comment: Thanks. This is not exactly complete for what I need though but it is a good start :)