# Selecting the 4-neighbours of a pixel

Tags: image, matlab, pixel, neighbours

How can I select the 4-neighbours of a pixel in `matlab`?

Thanks.

Comment: similar questions with vectorized solution: [MATLAB moving a point in the XY plane](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11127507) and [neighborhood radius in an image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11869406)

Answer (score 6):

If the the image is `img` and the current pixel indices are `i` and `j`, then the four neighbors will be:

```
img(i-1,j);
img(i+1,j);
img(i,j-1);
img(i,j+1);
```